# Join more than two tables by the same columns with Oracle USING clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables : Table1, Table2 and Table3.
The three tables contains 3 same columns SAMECOL1, SAMECOL2 and SAMECOL3.
Both tables Table1 and Table2 have the MY_PK_COL column which is the primary key of the Table1.

When I use this query in SQL Developer I get an error :

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.MY_PK_COL = Table2.MY_PK_COL 
JOIN Table3 USING (SAMECOL1, SAMECOL2, SAMECOL3)
```

> 918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

But when I use this it's ok :

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 USING (MY_PK_COL, SAMECOL1, SAMECOL2, SAMECOL3)
JOIN Table3 USING (SAMECOL1, SAMECOL2, SAMECOL3)
```

If I understand well, in the first query the 3 columns SAMECOLx are renamed with aliases such as SAMECOL1_1, SAMECOL2_1, SAMECOL3_1 so it should not be a problem for the second join with the USING clause (ambiguous thing).

So, where is the problem with the first query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I understand well, in the first query the 3 columns SAMECOLx are renamed with aliases such as SAMECOL1_1, SAMECOL2_1, SAMECOL3_1

No. The join operation does not rename the columns. If you queried just those two tables, with that join, then your client is choosing to add the `_1` part when it displays the results; it isn't part of the result set.

What you see depends on your client and how you run it. For example, SQL Developer will change the column headings as you describe in the 'Query Result' window if you run it as a query (run statement, or control-enter); but if you run it as a script (run script, or F5) then it doesn't do that in the 'Script Output' window. Neither does SQL*Plus, or SQLcl.

So the first part

```
Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.MY_PK_COL = Table2.MY_PK_COL
```

effectively makes all of the columns from both tables available for later processing, including two columns still called `SAMECOL1`, and then the next part

```
JOIN Table3 USING (SAMECOL1, SAMECOL2, SAMECOL3)
```

doesn't know which of the two columns you mean - it can't distinguish between `Table1.SAMECOL1` and `Table2.SAMECOL2`. *You* know they are the same data, but there is nothing in the query that says that is the case.

In the second form the first `USING` eliminates that ambiguity:

```
Table1
JOIN Table2 USING (MY_PK_COL, SAMECOL1, SAMECOL2, SAMECOL3)
```

only has a single `SAMECOL1` projected - which is kind of from both and neither of the source tables.

You can see the difference [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ePkME0Bt), which does *not* alias the duplicate columns in the first query as you assumed (and as your client does):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.MY_PK_COL = Table2.MY_PK_COL
```

| MY_PK_COL | SAMECOL1 | SAMECOL2 | SAMECOL3 | MY_PK_COL | SAMECOL1 | SAMECOL2 | SAMECOL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 42 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 USING (MY_PK_COL, SAMECOL1, SAMECOL2, SAMECOL3)
```

| MY_PK_COL | SAMECOL1 | SAMECOL2 | SAMECOL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: Thanks very clear answer ! But If I have different values between the columns SAMECOLx in Table1 and Table2 and I want to choose one of them to compare with the Table3. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Don't use `USING` for either join, and make the second join's replacement `ON` specify the condition properly - however you want to choose which to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you use only the first join you see the obvious difference

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 USING (MY_PK_COL, SAMECOL1, SAMECOL2, SAMECOL3);

 MY_PK_COL   SAMECOL1   SAMECOL2   SAMECOL3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1          1
         
SELECT * FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.MY_PK_COL = Table2.MY_PK_COL;

 MY_PK_COL   SAMECOL1   SAMECOL2   SAMECOL3  MY_PK_COL   SAMECOL1   SAMECOL2   SAMECOL3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1          1          1          1          1          1
```

So the point is while using the `ON condition` the `select *` returns *all columns from both tables* - which leads to your problem.

Join with `USING column` returns the *using columns* only once - unfortunately I can't find a documentation of this behavior, the closest [description](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) is

> In an outer join with the USING clause, the query returns a single column that coalesces the two matching columns in the join.

Comment: It depends on your client though; if you run the `ON` version in SQL Developer as a query (not a script) then in the query result window it 'helpfully' changes the column headings so you do see `SAMECOL1` and `SAMECOL1_1` as the OP described. Which makes it more confusing and less obvious.

Comment: My point was that the `USING` syntax returns the *using* columns only once in a `select *`  query, on contrary join with `ON` returns *all columns from both tables*. I wanted to point it out with a documentation link that I unfortunately can't find @AlexPoole

Comment: Yes, I'm not disagreeing with that, but the OP is confused because when they run that query *they* see different column headings so it doesn't look ambiguous - their client makes it look like there is only one `SAMECOL1`, which they then try to use, but that isn't the case. It is obvious in your output, but not in theirs...